# Does mean independence imply zero covariance?

Tags: self-study

I've got a question where there is a population of observations in (x,y) data points. y is mean independent of x (equal to zero no matter where x is conditioned at).
Could the covariance change if we added more data points that keep y mean independent?

Answer (score 1):

mean independence does indeed imply zero covariance.
I will show it for the discrete case.
Mean independence is defined as follows:

$$
\forall x E(Y|X=x)=E(Y)
$$

Therefore
$$\forall x \sum_y P(Y=y|X=x)y = \sum_y P(Y=y) y$$

Now, the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is defined as
$$ Cov(X,Y)=E(XY) - E(X) E(Y)$$

Now we need to check whether the covariance is 0. Here, I focus on $E(X)E(Y)$.
\begin{align}
E(X) E(Y) &= \left[ \sum_y P(Y=y)y \right] \left[ \sum_x P(X=x) x \right] \\
&= \sum_x \left[P(X=x) x \sum_y P(Y=y)y \right]    \\
&= \sum_x \left[P(X=x) x \sum_y P(Y=y|X=x)y \right] \\
&= \sum_x \sum_y \left[P(X=x, Y=y)x y \right] \\
&= E(XY)    
\end{align}

That means
$$ Cov(X,Y)=E(XY) - E(X) E(Y) = E(XY) - E(XY) = 0$$

Comment: thanks. I added more data points that kept the y mean 0, but the covariance changed by 0.538. These data points made the originally symmetrical (on the x-axis) graph non-symmetrical, so i've found the covariance only stays 0 if the graph is symmetrical on the x-axis. 
does mean independence still imply zero covariance in this case, because i'm a bit confused with the discrepancy between the mathematical proof and the data?

Comment: Are you sure that x and y are still mean independent? Your additional data points probably represent a dependency.

Comment: my mistake, i didn't exactly understand the meaning of conditional mean so i was adding points that did not result in mean independence. i've fixed it now :)